# Connect iPhones over WiFi signals without joining a WiFi network

Tags: ios, bonjour

In my iOS application I want to connect iPhones together using WiFi Signals.

Suppose i have 3 iPhones and all 3 have WiFi ON from Settings but no iPhone connected to any available WiFi network only WiFi setting is ON.

I know about "Bonjour services" and how to use that to connect iPhones together over WiFi but Bonjour requires connect all iPhones to same WiFi network.

So is it possible to connect iPhones over WiFi facility only, without joining any WiFi network?

Comment: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/MultipeerConnectivity/Reference/MultipeerConnectivityFramework/Introduction/Introduction.html

Answer (score 0):

Create access point from one iPhone and connect to it with another.

[Instructions from Apple](http://support.apple.com/kb/HT4517)

Comment: Please provide some reference to create Access Point.

Comment: Hotspot is working with cellular data, it doesn't allow using WiFi.